# Web pages without refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make rails app in which page does not get refresh by only using plain javascript.

As I am a beginner I want to learn all these concepts thats why I dont want much use of any framework/library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to create a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA). You can do that in combination with a Rails backend indeed.
A single page application is loaded once in the browser and it handles routing, rendering and communication with the server without page reloads. On the server side you can use Rails just as a json api.

Perhaps you should have a search on topics like single page application in VanillaJS. VanillaJS is just regular Javascript but it filters out frameworks on search engines because people are using it in blog posts to indicate they use plain javascript.